# Unnest a column containing json lists

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a table containing a column filled with json lists such as the one below :

```
 ID | json_col 
----+----------
 1  | [{"A":"foo11","B":"bar11"},{"A":"foo12","B":"bar12"}]
 2  | [{"A":"foo21","B":"bar21"}]
```

I wish to "unnest" it to get the following table :

```
 ID | A       | B
----+---------+------
 1  | "foo11" | "bar11"
 1  | "foo12" | "bar12"
 2  | "foo21" | "bar21"
```

Ideally I would keep track of the item's order and would get something like that :

```
 ID | json_col_id | A       | B
----+-------------+---------+-------
 1  | 1           | "foo11" | "bar11"
 1  | 2           | "foo12" | "bar12"
 2  | 1           | "foo21" | "bar21"
```

---

In some cases my situation is more complex as I have some nested json elements, so in these cases my input would be :

```
 ID | json_col 
----+----------
 1  | [{"A":"foo11", "B":[{"C":"bar111", "D":"baz111"},{"C":"bar112", "D":"baz112"}], {"A":"foo12","B":[{"C":"bar121", "D":"baz121"}]}]
 2  | [{"A":"foo21", "B":[{"C":"bar211", "D":"baz211"}]}]
```

And my desired output would be :

```
 ID | A       | C        | D
----+---------+----------+----------
 1  | "foo11" | "bar111" | "baz111"
 1  | "foo11" | "bar112" | "baz112"
 1  | "foo12" | "bar121" | "baz122"
 2  | "foo21" | "bar211" | "baz211"
```

And in a dream world :

```
 ID | json_col_id | B_id | A       | C        | D
----+-------------+----------------+----------+------------
 1  | 1           | 1    | "foo11" | "bar111" | "baz111"
 1  | 1           | 2    | "foo11" | "bar112" | "baz112"
 1  | 2           | 1    | "foo12" | "bar121" | "baz122"
 2  | 1           | 1    | "foo21" | "bar211" | "baz211"
```

---

I understood how to use *PostrgreSQL*'s `json::jscon_col -> "item" ->> "subitem" as my_new_col` syntax for a nested list but I don't know how to untangle the format presented here, where lists have a regular format but have irregular lengths.

I assume the answer must be [somewhere there](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-json.html) but I can't figure out and didn't find similar examples on SO.

Comment: You can use json_array_elements function to get JSON objects as rows. Then, you can access its attributes using -> operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can json_populate_recordset function.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-json.html
Best is use as lateral and must create type before.

```
postgres=# CREATE TYPE x AS (a int, b int);
CREATE TYPE
postgres=# CREATE TABLE y(id int, c json);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# INSERT INTO y VALUES(1,'[{"a":1},{"a":2,"b":3},{"b":4}]');
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# SELECT z.* FROM y, json_populate_recordset(NULL::x, c) z;
┌───┬───┐
│ a │ b │
╞═══╪═══╡
│ 1 │   │
│ 2 │ 3 │
│   │ 4 │
└───┴───┘
(3 rows)

postgres=#
```

===== edit: ====

example on your table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS moodys_table;
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE moodys_table ("ID" int, json_col json);
--INSERT INTO moodys_table VALUES (1, '[{"A":"foo11", "B":[{"C":"bar111", "D":"baz111"},{"C":"bar112", "D":"baz112"}],{"A":"foo12","B":[{"C":"bar121", "D":"baz121"}]}]'::json);
--missing braces in json
INSERT INTO moodys_table VALUES (1, '[{"A":"foo11", "B":[{"C":"bar111", "D":"baz111"},{"C":"bar112", "D":"baz112"}]},{"A":"foo12","B":[{"C":"bar121", "D":"baz121"}]}]'::json);
INSERT INTO moodys_table VALUES (2, '[{"A":"foo21", "B":[{"C":"bar211", "D":"baz211"}]}]'::json);

CREATE TYPE btype AS ("C" varchar, "D" varchar);
CREATE TYPE json_col_type AS ("A" text, "B" json); --btype[]);

SELECT * FROM moodys_table;

SELECT "ID", data."A", data2.*
, dense_rank() over(partition by "ID" ORDER BY "A") json_col_id
, dense_rank() over(partition by "ID", "A" ORDER BY "C", "D") b_id
--order in json array have no sense
FROM moodys_table
, json_populate_recordset(NULL::json_col_type, json_col) data
, json_populate_recordset(NULL::btype, "B") data2

;

ROLLBACK;
```

---

```
postgres=# \i /tmp/moodys.sql 
psql:/tmp/moodys.sql:1: NOTICE:  table "moodys_table" does not exist, skipping
DROP TABLE
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
CREATE TYPE
CREATE TYPE
┌────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ID │                                                             json_col                                                              │
╞════╪═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│  1 │ [{"A":"foo11", "B":[{"C":"bar111", "D":"baz111"},{"C":"bar112", "D":"baz112"}]},{"A":"foo12","B":[{"C":"bar121", "D":"baz121"}]}] │
│  2 │ [{"A":"foo21", "B":[{"C":"bar211", "D":"baz211"}]}]                                                                               │
└────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(2 rows)

┌────┬───────┬────────┬────────┬─────────────┬──────┐
│ ID │   A   │   C    │   D    │ json_col_id │ b_id │
╞════╪═══════╪════════╪════════╪═════════════╪══════╡
│  1 │ foo11 │ bar111 │ baz111 │           1 │    1 │
│  1 │ foo11 │ bar112 │ baz112 │           1 │    2 │
│  1 │ foo12 │ bar121 │ baz121 │           2 │    1 │
│  2 │ foo21 │ bar211 │ baz211 │           1 │    1 │
└────┴───────┴────────┴────────┴─────────────┴──────┘
(4 rows)

ROLLBACK
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to use it and lookup some examples but didn't get anywhere as all the examples I found were using raw json strings and not a column as input, or where too complicated (I don't know `PostgreSQL` much).

Comment: Changed in answer (added example). You can use, obviously add any columns from original table.

Comment: Thanks Jan, I went along with Diego's solution as it was directly applicable to my table and I didn't have to set types explicitly. I was also not sure how to adapt your solution featuring a string input to a solution using a table input.

Comment: But it is using table, y is table, c is column. Composite type is only template for record, you can create table instead of type (every table creates composite type).

Comment: sorry for being slow, so `x` is a template, and `y` is my input right ? So applied to my situation this should work ? `CREATE TABLE my_template(A int, B int); SELECT z.* FROM tbl, json_populate_recordset(NULL::my_template, json_col) z` . I get `No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts`

Comment: Apologies, your answer is fully reproducible, I was just confused by the format, I've not been able to apply it to my real case yet but working at it

Comment: Added example on your table. ^^

Comment: Thank you can congrats for your first accepted answer :). About "order in json array have no sense", I think you mean well conceived arrays right ? I prefer not to assume that order is unimportant as my json lists might describe a sequence of operations, that's why I need these id columns. Is there any reason why you would avoid `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION ...)` without order clause  ? it seems more general to me here, and more compact, maybe faster as we're not sorting/ranking ?

Comment: I mean, that order of elements in json array is not immutable (you can`t compare two jsons in postgre, because they can have different format, but data can be the same). About dense_rank. It is different function, try it, it returns different values. It gets you unique values for partition, but you want obtain same number for all rows with the same "A".

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps:

```
WITH X AS
(
    SELECT 
        JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(cod_proj::JSON) AS jsonelement
    FROM temp.kmltests
)
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY jsonelement->>'A'),
    jsonelement->'A' AS A,

    -- Use a CASE to determine if B is a scalar value or an array.
    -- If B is a scalar value, simply access jsonelement->'B'

    JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(jsonelement->'B')->'C' AS C,
    JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(jsonelement->'B')->'D' AS D
FROM X xx
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I got it to work, I just have to find a way to add these unique IDs, I wish there was a way to unnest everything without being explicit but it doesn't seem possible from the doc.

Comment: Those unique IDs are a bit more complicated since they are related to each object. ROW_NUMBER may not help in this case.

Comment: Thanks Diego, I think to have both IDs the only choice is to do it in two steps, I detailed how I made it work in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Reworking the answer from @diego-victor-de-jesus to add the ID columns and adding some details.

Let my table be named `tbl`:

- `json_array_elements()` expends a json list, repeating the values from other columns,
- `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mycolumn)` gives me incremental ids within groups.

As I want 2 different `IDs` I need to repeat this sequence 2 times, peeling a layer at a time.

```
SELECT 
ID, json_col_id,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY json_col_id) as B_id,
A,
B ->> 'C' AS C,
B ->> 'D' AS D
FROM
(SELECT 
ID, json_col_id, A,
JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(B::JSON) AS B
FROM
(SELECT 
ID,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID) as json_col_id,
json_col ->> 'A' AS A,
json_col -> 'B' AS B
FROM 
(SELECT 
index,
JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(json_col::JSON) AS json_col
FROM tbl
) AS expanded_json_col) AS extracted_json_col) as expanded_B"
```